unittest module cannot find a third module
I'm developing a simple application in python which can be summarized in these files:

root_dir

myLib (contains some modules in python)
libraryUnderTest (contains some modules in python that import some modules from myLib directory

TEST (contains the unittest program)





in particular, let's assume that my test_program.py is :
import sys
import os
import unittest
from  unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import patch
import socket
lib_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../'))
sys.path.append(lib_path)
import libUnderTest as lut
    
class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        """
        Simple Test
        """
        tmp = lut.myObject(100, "int32", "pathToFile")
        self.assertEqual(tmp.memSize, 100)
        self.assertEqual(tmp.dtype, 4)
        self.assertEqual(tmp.pathToFile, "pathToFile")
        self.assertEqual(tmp.logged, False)enter code here

And my program in libraryUnderTest/libUnderTest.py
import sys
sys.path.append("../myLib")
import helperLib as helpLib

'''
This class represents a memRegion as it is in the XML conf tag
'''
class GpuSatMemRegion:
    def __init__(self, memSize, type, defValue, pathToFile = None):
        self.memReg = helpLib.anotherObject(memSize, type)
        self.memSize  
        self.type = type
        self.defValue=defValue
        self.pathToFile = pathToFile 
        self.logged = False

Why is  my test_program failing with this message?
File "C:\Users\Benelli\Desktop\SVN\GPUatSAT-SVN\trunk\sw\GpuOnServer\libraryUnderTest \libUnderTest.py", line 3, in 
import helperLib as helpLib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helperLib '
How can I avoid this inconvenience?

This question is similar to: Relative imports for the billionth time. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
